# HTML and Native Javascript Change Iframe content based on search query

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I've made a website that utilizes Bootstrap's tab navigation. For my blog, I have an iframe set into one of these tabs. I am currently trying to make it so that if I were to give someone a link with the query `?blogPost=a_post` it would automatically redirect the SRC of the Iframe to `/blog/a_post.html`. I started by setting up the script to get the queries based on this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/get-url-parameters-with-javascript/. Then, I adapted the code to look like this:

```js
function onload() {
            let queryString = window.location.search;
            let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
            if (urlParams.has('blogPost')) {
              let blogPost = urlParams.get('blogPost');
              document.getElementById('pills-home-tab').classList.remove('active');
              document.getElementById('pills-blog-tab').classList.add('active');
              document.getElementById("child-iframe").src = `./blog/${blogPost}.html`;
            } else {
              return;
            }
          }
          window.onload = onload;
```

However, when I load the page `https://website.com/?blogPost=welcome_to_my_blog` none of the `classList` properties change, and the Iframe stays at `/blog.html`

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, but I'm certain what I'm trying to do is possible, and under that assumption know I am at error in my code. No errors come up on my browser's console, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a global function called `onload`, this has overwritten the native `window.onload`, making it not work. You can change the name of your function, or just add directly like this:

```
window.onload = () => {
        let queryString = window.location.search;
        let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        if (urlParams.has("blogPost")) {
          let blogPost = urlParams.get("blogPost");
          document.getElementById("pills-home-tab").classList.remove("active");
          document.getElementById("pills-blog-tab").classList.add("active");
          document.getElementById("child-iframe").src = `./blog/${blogPost}.html`;
        }
      };
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! The only problem left is making sure Bootstrap changes the tabs, too. It changed the active button and Iframe content, but not tabs. I'll figure that one out, though. Thank you!